# Does a template type waste space in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I was going through [EASTL's list class](http://zalcetto.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source/EASTL/include/EASTL/list.h) to look at how the author has implemented the nodes. My expectation was a simplistic class/structure. Instead, I see a base and a node that is inheriting from this base (still simplistic, but why two classes?). His comments explain why:

> We define a ListNodeBase separately from ListNode (below), because it allows
>   us to have non-templated operations such as insert, remove (below), and it 
>   makes it so that the list anchor node doesn't carry a T with it, which would
>   waste space and possibly lead to surprising the user due to extra Ts existing
>   that the user didn't explicitly create. The downside to all of this is that 
>   it makes debug viewing of a list harder, given that the node pointers are of 
>   type ListNodeBase and not ListNode. However, see ListNodeBaseProxy below.

I don't understand a couple of things here. I *do* understand the part about why it will make debug viewing a bit harder, but what does he mean by `list anchor node doesn't carry a T with it` and `would waste space and possibly lead to surprising the user due to extra Ts existing that the user didn't explicitly create`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the helper class, the list root node would contain an instance of T that is never used. The second sentence is saying that you might not expect an empty list to create a T. For example, creating a T might have side effects.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the idea is to separate the abstraction of the list, from the data it carries. You only need the `ListNode` when you actually want to access the data, all the rest can be done on the abstract `ListNodeBase`. That's how I understand the `list anchor node doesn't carry a T with it`.

There's something there about space. Template classes are created per type, so if you have several different types used for `T`, without the `ListNodeBase` you would be creating templated copies of all the operations per type, with it - you don't, and the `LinkNode` inherits them, and only requires the memory for the actual data. Seems that the space saved refers to the actual size of the code in this case.

Comment: You don't use a list with no data. There's a single node called **anchor node** or **sentinel** that is present in each instance of the list, even in the empty list, to eliminate some special-case code associated with empty lists. It's this one node that does not need to contain user's data.

Comment: @n.m. that would be the class `list`, you can take a look at the implementation at the link the OP posted. Since the `list` itself is the sentinel, the point is moot.

Comment: I have looked. As far as I can tell, the `list` *contains* the sentinel, at the `base_node_type mNode;` line.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to support empty lists. If the head node itself always contains one T, and every list contains a head node, then it follows that every list contains at least one T, and therefore never can be empty.